# Accessing properties of javascript objects using type dynamic in C# 4

Tags: reflection, dynamic, c#-4.0, properties

I define a com object as a dynamic type in c# I am able to call methods quite easily.
However when I try to access a property on the same object I get an invalid cast exception.

The object in question is an array, passed to managed code from JavaScript, and I wish to get the length property of it as an int.

I know I am missing something odd because I am not getting a 'does not contain a definition' exception and I can  access the property easily using reflection/InvokeMember.

Why can I not convert the length property of the dynamic type to an int?

For example

**This Fails**

```
   dynamic com = comObject;
   int i = com.length; // RTBE here.
```

**This Works**

```
   Type type = comObject.GetType();
   int i = (int)type.InvokeMember("length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null);
```

*** Update ***

After a lot of testing I have narrowed this oddness to cases of multi-dimensional arrays.
The com object in question is a parameter passed from a html document to managed code. For all intents and purposes the object sometimes looks like this in JavaScript.

```
var x = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
```

When an array like this comes to managed code I am able to get the length AOK using the type dynamic. (i.e. the first example here that fails actually works). However, if it is a multi-dimensional array such as the following structure in JavaScript.

```
var y = [["b1", "b2", "b3"], "a2", "a3"];
```

Then I get an error when trying to access its length property dynamically. Note, I can still access the length via reflection in this case. It seems to me that for some reason the length property does not get correctly mapped when a multidimensional array is used as a dynmaic type...

In my case what I have done to solve(!?) this is add a 'length_' property to the array like so before passing it.

```
var y = [["b1", "b2", "b3"], "a2", "a3"];
y.length_ = y.length;
```

Now in managed code I can accesses this property as expected without error. Far from ideal but seems to work...

```
   dynamic com = comObject;
   int i = com.length_; // 3!
```

**Further Update**

Ok, so it seems that as well as the length property the objects index gets lost to the dynamic type as well. Again it is accessible via reflection though...

**Fails**

```
   dynamic com = comObject; // js array i.e. var x = [1, 2];
   int i = com[0]; // MissingMemberException - Error while invoking [PROPERTYGET, DISPID(0)].
   int i = com["0"]; // MissingMemberException - Error while invoking [PROPERTYGET, DISPID(0)].
```

**Works**

```
   Type type = comObject.GetType();
   int i = (int)type.InvokeMember("0", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null); // 1
```

Comment: What is `int com.property` in real life?

Comment: is the length property on a javascript object.

Comment: ..I tried int i = Convert.ToInt32(com.property); as well...

Comment: have you tried var i = com.property?

Comment: @Taylor - Yes, same ICE using var

Comment: @Gabe I will post actual code, wait one...

Comment: You have a reference to a dynamic object so why not just assign directly to the variable?  `int i = com.length;`  The DLR will do what is necessary to make the assignment work (if it is indeed possible).  The conversion you try to do prevents it from doing what is needed AFAIK.

Comment: Are you running this in a separate thread (i.e. other than the main UI thread)?

Comment: @CodeNaked - yes, it is running via a background-worker, could this be the issue? FYI it is really puzzling me now because if I call .valueOf() on the same dynamic type I get a result!

Comment: What is the runtime type of the `length` property?  It appears it is not actually a `System.Int32` but something else.

Comment: @Jeff M it is System.__ComObject

Comment: @Fraser - All signs point to yes. Try running your code from the main UI thread and see if it fails. If so, then it has something to do with marshaling your COM object across threads (i.e. STA/MTA).

Comment: @CodeNaked Ok, I will set up a test to see if this is the case...thanks.

Comment: @CodeNaked - no dice, even with a simple case (1 thread) I can access the length property as an integer via reflection but not via type dynamic. FYI - the exceptions are the same. ICE with the convert, RTB without...

Comment: @Fraser - Can you do com.length.GetType() and see what type that returns?

Comment: @CodeNaked - com.length is {Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"} when a multidimensional array, Int32 when it is an array of single dimensions. I think that c# somehow messes up the length property when the array is multidimensional. Just frustrating as it *is* accessible via reflection.

Comment: @Fraser - Ok, next what does "type.InvokeMember("0", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null).GetType()" return? I'm guessing Int32 :-)

Comment: @CodeNaked - yes, that is correct...See the answer I have given below - you should see the oddness behind the problem clearly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms you can't access the length property of a multi-dimensional array in c# via the type dynamic unless, it seems, you have used the length property in JavaScript first...

The simple test below shows this very clearly. I hope this saves someone else the head scratching I have been having over the last day or so.

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;

        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<script>");
        html.Append("var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];");
        html.Append("var arr2 = [arr1, 2, 3, 4];");
        html.Append("var fn1 = function() { return arr1; };");
        html.Append("var fn2 = function() { return arr2; };");
        html.Append("var fn3 = function() { alert(arr2.length); }");
        html.Append("</script>");
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = html.ToString();

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            dynamic arr1 = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("fn1");
            int i = arr1.length;
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); //4

            // If I call fn3 here then the arr2.length *is* available as int i2 below!
            ////webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("fn3"); // 4 

            dynamic arr2 = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("fn2");
            int i2 = arr2.length;
            MessageBox.Show(i2.ToString()); // unless fn3 is called you get...
            /* 
            System.MissingMemberException was unhandled by user code
            Message=Error while invoking length.
            Source=System.Dynamic
            StackTrace:
            at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
            at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject )
            at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
            at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
            at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
            */             
        };
    }
}
```

**update**

It seems (see comments) that this behaviour is fixed if the WebBrowser control uses version 9 of Internet Explorer (...the control uses the version of IE on the machine). I can only presume  that the IE9 'Chakra' JavaScript engine is doing something extra/different to the old js engine in this case.

Comment: If you access the length via reflection before using dynamic, does the dynamic work? I'm wondering if the reflection "fixes" the issue like accessing length via javascript.

Comment: @CodeNaked - yes, it does! accessing the property via reflection makes it available via dynamic too. Indeed. It seems if you access it either in js or c# by some other means then it is available, but it is somehow uninitialised if you first access it via type dynamic. v.odd.

Comment: What is still puzzling is what is the underlying object in the wrapper and if I can cast it to a managed type. I am going to ask another question based on this and continue to play with it...

Comment: @Fraser - I just tried your code above in a new project and it worked fine! Did New WinForms App, Added WebBrowser to Form1, Set ComVisible(true) in AssemblyInfo, and added your code. If I run as you have above, I get two message boxes showing 4. I have VS2010 SP1 installed, not sure if that matters.

Comment: @Fraser - I also have IE9 installed.

Comment: @CodeNaked - Ok I am running VS c# express 2010, IE is v 8.0.6. I might try and upgrade IE to see if that makes a difference. Maybe the IE9 Chakra engine is doing something extra?

Comment: @CodeNaked - yes! the IE9 upgrade fixes it, amazing stuff. Obviously the old js engine was doing something funky.