# Check/uncheck checkbox in a webBrowser Control without an ID

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, checkbox

i need to check a checkbox in my webbrowser control  the thing is this checkbox has no ID 
so i can't use the GetElementById() method

this is HTML code of the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="shoulduselikescheckbox" defaultchecked="true"  >
```

Comment: You can try using xpath. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355386/using-xpath-and-webbrowser-control-to-select-multiple-nodes

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case select element by it's `class name`

if you just using javascript then should work,

```
var cbArray = document.getElementsByClassName('shoulduselikescheckbox');
var cb= cbArray [0];
```

Comment: you want to `check` the checkbox at client side, right? if yes then suggested option will work no matter what server side language you're using.

Comment: You should really remove the jQuery version - it's of no use to the OP.