# Web_Browser Control VB.NET(VS2015 Comm) : How to get selected element's Xpath?

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-2015

Web_Browser Control VB.NET(VS2015 Comm) : I've developed a program which will return me HTMLElement's attributes, But i'm looking for the logic to get HTMLElement's Xpath.

Thank You,
Ed D, India.

Comment: You can not using IE (Web Browser Control). You need a third party library (api) to do this...

Comment: [Have you tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355386/using-xpath-and-webbrowser-control-to-select-multiple-nodes)

Comment: @Zaggler : Do You know such API ?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid : Thanks, but that is different thing..

Comment: Yes but it can give you the idea of how you can get elements using XPath.